# Rails 5.1 api render json doubling relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

With Rails 5.1.1 I have a problem where rendering JSON is somehow "doubling" the number of relationships.

There is a has_many / belongs_to relationship, nothing fancy.  A "user" has many "codes".  Stepping through the `users_controller#update` method I see the following:

Check what is coming in from the params:

```
(byebug) user_params['codes_attributes'].count
2
```

Check what is saved after `@user.update(user_params)` was called:

```
(byebug) @user.codes.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE "codes"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 85]]
2
```

Lastly, a straight `as_json` doubles via the relationship as well:

```
(byebug) @user.codes.as_json.count
4
```

Check what is output from `as_json` (`to_json` is the same):

```
(byebug) @user.as_json(include: [:friend, :codes])['codes'].count
4
(byebug) @user.codes.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE "codes"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 85]]
2
```

And here we can see that somehow the number of relationships magically doubled!  Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I was making use of a custom function to save associations (autosave_associated_records_for_codes) which seems to have introduced the problem.  I've commented it out for now but will try to revisit why exactly it was doubling things up.  Once I figure out the exact cause will reply back with a solution.

Comment: aren't you doing something weird in the `as_json` method of your `Code` model ?

Comment: I wish I was ... but unfortunately I'm not.  I have some custom code in `User#autosave_associated_records_for_codes` as part of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ... trying to figure out if that is somehow related.

Comment: You didn't show the `as_json` output

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in rails, though i suggest you to try this. Iam not sure about it, but you should give it a try.

```
  def get_codes_count
    self.codes.count
  end
```

And then if you want a  count then you can just do

```
  @user.as_json(method: :get_codes_count)
```

Comment: Hi @bhavesh-waghela thanks for the idea, I think I have found the problem (see UPDATE above) but will investigate this option if things continue to misbehave.